# Magento error There are no printable documents related to selected orders." when number of items in order exceeds 9

Tags: magento

I am getting the error "There are no printable documents related to selected orders." when I try printpackingslip on a local copy of Magento. It's Magento 1.9. I get this error only when I try printing an order with more than 9 items. The printing works just fine for 7 items( I have tested it). I have tried the solution given on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17902/cant-generate-pdf-invoices-or-packing-slips-in-magento but, it didn't work.

Comment: Are you getting this for all the orders?

Comment: No, only for orders with more than 9 items. It looks like, when i exceeds one page i get this error. since in one page, i can almost have 9 items but when i exceed it, it shows error

Comment: Have you disabled some of the products?

Comment: No, All products are active